# Button at the slide image is not moving automatically.

Tags: w3.css

I have created images with automatic slides. As well as button/indicators at the below of the image. These automatic slides are working perfectly, but not the buttons. While slide1 moves to the next slide2 automatically, the button should show that it's on second image. The below code is under w3.css

```
<html>
<title>Hotel</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>
<body>
<div class="w3-container w3-center">
  <h2>Slideshow</h2>
 </div>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/burger.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/piz.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/prawns.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
//automatic slide
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://product-assets.faasos.io/production/product/image_1528968692627_ADB.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://product-assets.faasos.io/production/product/image_1528968637811_A%20LA%20CARTE.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://product-assets.faasos.io/production/product/image_1528968877199_DESSERTS.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```